# Expected value of Ito integral product for diferent time intervals

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I know that:
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^af(t)dB(t)\int_a^bf(t)dB(t) \right]
 = \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^af(t)dB(t) \right]
   \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_a^bf(t)dB(t) \right]
 = 0,$$
where $0<a<b$, because Brownian motions don't 'overlap' and are independent.

However, I can not find no credible source where this fact is stated or proven. Can you recommend where could I find this fact or theorems which lead to this fact, something like:
$$\mathbb{E}\int_0^af(t)dB(t)\int_0^bf(t)dB(t)=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^{\min(a,b)}f(t)dB(t)\right)^2=\int_0^{\min(a,b)}f^2(t)dt.$$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a more general fact:

**Proposition** Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ be two adapted processes such that for a deterministic time $T > 0$ we have $\int_0^T E[X^2(t)]dt < \infty$ and $\int_0^T E[Y^2(t)]dt < \infty$. Then $$E \left[ \int_0^T X_t dB_t \int_0^T Y_t dB_t \right] = \int_0^T E[X_t Y_t] dt$$

Using this proposition, and assuming $f \in L^2$ and $a <b$, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
E \left[ \int_0^a f(t) dB_t \int_a^b f(t)  dB_t \right] &= E \left[ \int_0^b f(t) 1_{\{ t \le a \}}dB_t \int_0^b f(t) 1_{ \{a \le t \le b\} } dB_t \right] \\
&= \int_0^b E[f^2(t) 1_{\{ t \le a \}}1_{ \{a \le t \le b\} }] dt = 0
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! You see, I have the proof of this myself, but I do not want to use it. I want a reference.

Comment: @TheGrandDuke You can find a version of this in Corollary 2.3.5 of Kuo's Introduction to Stochastic Integration.